# How to narrow screen sharing options like Google Meet does?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using [MediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia) to record user's screen.

In theory, I can't narrow the choices from JS ...

> The specified constraints can't be used to limit the options available to the user. Instead, they must be applied after the user chooses a source, in order to generate output that matches the constraints.

but, somehow Google Meet does it (Windows + Chrome)? But how?

[image]

I've tried

```js
{
  video: {
    displaySurface: 'application' | 'browser' | 'monitor' | 'window'
  }
}
```

but I always get the dialog window with all the options.

I would like to have it working at least on Chrome.

Comment: on firefox and mac os x I can choose from all the sources even on meet, whatever option I click

Comment: Somehow it is done on Windows and Chrome but I can't find it in the source code. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a [MediaStreamConstrain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints) to `.getDisplayMedia()` to specify the attributes on the video stream you want.

The MediaStreamConstrain is an object such as:

```
{
  audio: {...},
  video: {...},
}
```

Audio and video can be a boolean (basic usage) or [MediaTrackConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints). If you use a MediaTrackConstrain, you can specify what you want to record:

```
{
  video: {
    displaySurface: 'application' | 'browser' | 'monitor' | 'window'
  }
}
```

See the [MediaTrackConstrain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints) reference for more advanced usage

Comment: I've already tried it and it doesn't work. That's why I'm asking 

Comment: according to the "Browser compatibility" only Opera supports this constraint. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/displaySurface